# get all keys of play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Tags: json, scala, collections, playframework, playframework-json

I have to store `play.api.libs.json.JsValue` keys to a List. How i do this?

```
var str = ???                        //json String
val json: JsValue = Json.parse(str)
val data=json.\("data")
println(data)                       //[{"3":"4"},{"5":"2"},{"4":"5"},{"2":"3"}]
val newIndexes=List[Long]()
```

expecting

```
newIndexes=List(3,5,4,2)
```

Comment: Do you mean all keys in all json objects, even in nested ones?

Answer (score 7):

If you want to get all keys in the json you can do it recursively with

```
def allKeys(json: JsValue): collection.Set[String] = json match {
  case o: JsObject => o.keys ++ o.values.flatMap(allKeys)
  case JsArray(as) => as.flatMap(allKeys).toSet
  case _ => Set()
}
```

Note that the order is not preserved as `values` in `JsObject` is a `Map`.

Another option is to use the `Seq` of fields in `JsObject` instead of using the `keys`:

```
def allKeys(json: JsValue): Seq[String] = json match {
  case JsObject(fields) => fields.map(_._1) ++ fields.map(_._2).flatMap(allKeys)
  case JsArray(as) => as.flatMap(allKeys)
  case _ => Seq.empty[String]
}
```

This way you will get a breadth-first order of all keys in json object.