# Scala foreach member variable

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, case-class

Is there a way to loop for each member variable of a class? It's trivial with Lists and arrays but I have to construct a case class with each json field mapping to a member variable to use the Play framework's Reads/validator API

Comment: Could you clarify?  Do you mean iterate over every property in a class instance?

Comment: yup, that is what I mean

Comment: From your question I have a feeling you're doing something wrong. Can you elaborate on what exactly you're trying to do, with an example maybe?

Comment: I want to periodically get from a uri and compare every field of the returned json with the previous value and log a message if a field has changed. I use the Play framework to validate the json and convert into a class

Comment: It depends on what you encapsulating the "returned json" as - is is a custom class?  A map?  A JSON library object?   Would help answer.

Comment: play.api.libs.json.JsValue

Comment: Sounds like may be same question as this?: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26650354/get-all-keys-of-play-api-libs-json-jsvalue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you mean something like this:

```
case class SomeClass(a: Int, b: Int)
SomeClass(1,2).productIterator.foreach{ a => println(a)}
```

this will give you an output of: 1 2

Or if you are trying to construct an object from json. You can define reads in your case class which deserialises json to your object :

```
override def reads(json: JsValue): JsResult[SomeClass] = JsSuccess(SomeClass(
    (json \ "a").as[Int],
    (json \ "b").as[Int]
  )
  )
```

then to use the deserialisation:

```
val json = Json.obj() //Your json
json.validate[SomeClass]

json.fold(
  errors => {
    Json.obj("status" -> "Not OK", "message" -> JsError.toJson(errors))
  },
  preset => {
    Json.obj("status" -> "OK")
  }
)
```

Comment: Thanks, I already did the conversion to a class object. The productIterator part is what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

If you want compare `Json` and get difference, may be better use `JsObject` methods?

For example `fieldSet` return all fields as a set. You can use `diff` on previous and current field set to get changed fields. This is fast solution and no any specific classes.